# Using the less than comparison operator for strings in F#

Tags: linq, f#, operators

I'm trying to write a F# query as follows

```
let extract = 
    query {
        for trade in Schema.Trade do
        where (trade.Year + trade.Month <= "202007")
        take 100
        select (trade)
    }
```

The problem is that both Year and Month are `string`.

I see an exception coming from `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule` saying that

`LessThanOrEqual` is not defined for the types '`System.String`' and '`System.String`'.

Why not? Is there a different operator?

To give you more context, the query is running inside SQLProvider and, if I write only `=` instead of `<=`, the auto-generated sql already translates the `+` into a correct

```
CONCAT(`trade`.`year`, `trade`.`month`)
```

So that part is not an issue on the SQLProvider side.

### C# underlying code

Let me rephrase what *I think* is happening under the cover.
Sorry, this is just my fealing about the analysis of the problem, I don't want to confuse things. Anyway, I huess that something like the following is happening (this is C# interactive)

```
> Expression<Func<String>> ex1 = () => "202006";;
> Expression<Func<String>> ex2 = () => "202005";;
> Expression.GreaterThan(ex1.Body, ex2.Body);;
System.InvalidOperationException: L'operatore binario GreaterThan non è definito per i tipi 'System.String' e 'System.String'.
  + System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedBinaryOperatorOrThrow(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType, string, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, bool)
  + System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GreaterThan(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, bool, System.Reflection.MethodInfo)
```

### Stack Trace

This is instead the real, full stack trace from the above said F# program.

```
</ExceptionType><Message>L'operatore binario LessThanOrEqual non è definito per i tipi 'System.String' e 'System.String'.</Message><StackTrace>   in System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedBinaryOperatorOrThrow(ExpressionType binaryType, String name, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull)
   in System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext@512-7.Invoke(Tuple`2 tupledArg)
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 512
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 734
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.mapToFreshConsTail[a,b](FSharpList`1 cons, FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:riga 241
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:riga 252
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprsToLinq(ConvEnv env, FSharpList`1 es) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 820
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 642
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:riga 250
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprsToLinq(ConvEnv env, FSharpList`1 es) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 820
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 642
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 734
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation(FSharpExpr e) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 844
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedInner(CanEliminate canElim, FSharpExpr queryProducingSequence) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Query.fs:riga 1823
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.clo@1926-1.Microsoft-FSharp-Linq-ForwardDeclarations-IQueryMethods-Execute[a,b](FSharpExpr`1 q) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Query.fs:riga 1928
   in Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\FunctionalCmd\Program.fs:riga 23</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: L'operatore binario LessThanOrEqual non è definito per i tipi 'System.String' e 'System.String'.
   in System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedBinaryOperatorOrThrow(ExpressionType binaryType, String name, Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull)
   in System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext@512-7.Invoke(Tuple`2 tupledArg)
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 512
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 734
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.mapToFreshConsTail[a,b](FSharpList`1 cons, FSharpFunc`2 f, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:riga 241
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:riga 252
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprsToLinq(ConvEnv env, FSharpList`1 es) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 820
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 642
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\local.fs:riga 250
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprsToLinq(ConvEnv env, FSharpList`1 es) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 820
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 642
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.ConvExprToLinqInContext(ConvEnv env, FSharpExpr inp) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 734
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation(FSharpExpr e) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Linq.fs:riga 844
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedInner(CanEliminate canElim, FSharpExpr queryProducingSequence) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Query.fs:riga 1823
   in Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.clo@1926-1.Microsoft-FSharp-Linq-ForwardDeclarations-IQueryMethods-Execute[a,b](FSharpExpr`1 q) in F:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\Query.fs:riga 1928
   in Program.main(String[] argv) in C:\FunctionalCmd\Program.fs:riga 23</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' in FSharp.Core.dll
L'operatore binario LessThanOrEqual non è definito per i tipi 'System.String' e 'System.String'.
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in the query translation, as string implements `IComparable`. You might want to report it.

Comment: Those are part of F#, and so you can report it against the F# repo here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to the C# equivalent described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814278/how-to-implement-lessthan-etc-when-building-expressions-on-strings).

Indeed if we look at [linq2db ExpressionEqualityComparer](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/60cbc66bf827dfde561cfd489a22d94d7cbbcf85/Source/LinqToDB/Expressions/ExpressionEqualityComparer.cs#L357)
they point to a `CompareBinary`

whilst [SQLProvider SqlRuntime.Patterns](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/12a8f81d52d30ea18cf33083470b35722b2deb28/src/SQLProvider/SqlRuntime.Patterns.fs#L193) is pointing to a `ConditionOperator.GreaterThan`

```
| ExpressionType.GreaterThan,        (:? BinaryExpression as ce) -> Some (ConditionOperator.GreaterThan,  ce.Left,ce.Right)
```

That could be (see @Abel comment)

> a bug in the query translation, as `string` implements `IComparable`

I've solved this by switching to C# (that is more robust and prevents the runtime exception with a compile error, coherent with its syntax, as opposite to what happens in F#) and linq2db (that is also more mature and robust than F# SQL type provider)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a database readily available to try this, but I think the issue is that you cannot reasonably compare strings in SQL query. While it is reasonable to concatenate strings and check for equality on strings, I don't think a comparison on strings would do what you want.

I would try re-writing the condition using something like this:

```
let extract = 
    query {
        for trade in Schema.Trade do
        where (int trade.Year < 2020 || 
          (int trade.Year = 2020 && int trade.Month <= 7))
        take 100
        select (trade)
    }
```

I assume you want a query that selects trades before July 2020, so I encoded that using a more elaborate condition that takes either trades before 2020 or 2020 trades before or in July.

Comment: @Giulio Ah, I did not know that! I guess I do not trust string comparison, so I did not think that would work :-). There should be some way to do this with integers though. Would it work if you replaced `int` with `Int32.Parse`? I will see if I can get a SQL database to try this myself!

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```ml
let extract = 
    let limitDate = System.DateTime(2020,08,01)
    query {
        for trade in Schema.Trade do
        where (trade < limitDate)
        take 100
        select (trade)
    }
```